# Database has thousands of randomly named tables

Tags: mysql, security, mysql-5.1, centos

Preface: First of all excuse me for bringing forwarding this weird question, as it could be just me.

Situation: We have a Centos 6.5 Cloud VPS hosting our website, running MySQL 5.1 and it is also used for two way replication to and from our in house MySQL server.

Problem: I recently restarted MySQL for changing some buffer size, when I tried to login, the existing password didn't work and I was able to login using *root@localost* with an empty password, which raised my suspicions.

When I entered in MySQL DB (to see user table for permissions) I have noticed that there are more than 5k tables, named randomly and few of them have binary data in it too. I can also see in */var/lib/mysql/mysql/* all of the tables have their data files present too.

I suspect having older version of OS and MySQL, our server has been hacked and hacker has injected some code and files there (I can see lots of DLLs and EXE files there, luckily it's a Linux server!)

I want to get rid of these useless tables and protect my server in a safe manner, as this is live customer facing web portal, so I can't try any unsafe deletion.

It is just a simple web app to take orders from clients and store in DB. I guess our system was hacked/compromised. The VPS provider is reliable and we have been with them for many years. I agree it could be incompetence on our part or theirs that we have never bothered to upgrade Centos 6.5 neither MySQL 5.1

Comment: Still, the presence of dlls and .exes is strange. But if it's hackers, they must be fairly incompetent putting them on a unix box? :-) And if they want just to be malicious, they could have picked more discreet file extensions. Do any of the names of these files mean anything to you? They're not a Windows distro of MySQL? I'm running out of ideas... Arrange with your provider to do a clean swap to a new server and monitor the situation after that?

Comment: You can check the DLLs and .exe files via an online security site (if they are similar to some known worm/virus/threat)

Comment: A PHP program, simply by not escaping user input, can expose the entire system to a hacker.  The VPS provider can protect from that.

Comment: @RickJames - sorry couldn't get you "simply by not escaping user input", can you pls explain it. thanks.

Comment: Suggest you research "sql injection" -- it is a big security issue.

Comment: @Vérace you are right, presence of windows files are strange and looks hackers didn't realize which OS we have. none of these files name or the mysql file names doesn't mean or resemble with any of our data or files. not sure if they are windows distro of mysql, few of them are named as:  "C:\y.exe" , "c:windowssystem3222073_64.os", "\usr\lib64\mysql\plugin\nusql.dll", "c:\windows\system32\wbem\mof\consb2.mof" and many more - most of them are dll and exe

Comment: @RickJames ok sure, someone suggested me to read and follow this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server - what do u think is it worth trying?

Comment: Sure read that serverfault page; it has a lot of info, some of which is about sql injection.  Wikipedia has a general discussion, including simple examples of how it is done.  A web search for "site:stackexchange.com sql injection php" yields a several forum entries on this forum.  Etc.